# Thunking __stdcall function with stack adjustment

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I'd like to thunk (by adjusting the stack) __stdcall function. For example a caller think is has a pointer to a callback function with the following prototype:

```
int Func(int a);
```

I'd like to write a thunk (that will be passed as a callback) that adjust the call to the following function prototype:

```
int Func(char* ptr, int a);
```

I know that when my thunk will be called that stack layout is:

```
------------------
|       a        |
------------------
| return address | <-- Top of the stack
------------------
```

I'd like to adjust the stuck to:

```
------------------
|       a        |
------------------
------------------
|       ptr      |
------------------
| return address | <-- Top of the stack
------------------
```

and then do a relative jump to relevant function (this way when the called function return the stack is balanced)

Here is my final thunk that works (of course it has to be packed and dynamically loaded to executable memory), Kudo to Jester for helping with assembly hex code for needed instructions !

```
struct Thunk
{
    BYTE    m_popRet;
    BYTE    m_pushPtr;          
    DWORD   m_ptr;         
    BYTE    m_pushRet;         
    BYTE    m_jmp;          
    DWORD   m_relProc;      
    BOOL Init(DWORD_PTR proc, void* ptr)
    {
        m_popRet  = 0x58;       
        m_pushPtr = 0x68; 
        m_ptr     = PtrToUlong(ptr);
        m_pushRet = 0x50;
        m_jmp     = 0xE9;
        m_relProc = DWORD((INT_PTR)proc - ((INT_PTR)this + sizeof Thunk));
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you described the stack layout, not sure what you have a problem with.
Anyway, if you want to use `JMP` your code could look like:

```
pop eax  ; 58             return address
push ptr ; 68 xx xx xx xx
push eax ; 50             put return address back
jmp proc ; E9 xx xx xx xx
```

Note that this will change stack alignment, so if you are in an environment where that matters, you will have to adjust the code. A somewhat more civilized version could be:

```
push edx     ; 52             align stack
push [esp+8] ; FF 74 24 08    "a"
push ptr     ; 68 xx xx xx xx
call proc    ; E9 xx xx xx xx
pop edx      ; 5A
ret 4        ; C2 04 00
```

Comment: The question seems interesting, but I don't understand what is being asked. Since you somehow determined that, you might want to edit the question.

Comment: @anatolyg not sure what needs clearing up? He said he wants to create a thunk function which can be passed as a callback having prototype `int Func(int a);` and which should then call another function `int Func(char* ptr, int a);` To do this you need to change the stack layout as per the diagrams OP provided. He basically wants to create `int thunk(int a) { return proc(ptr, a); }`

Comment: SO the question was "what is wrong with my code" and the answer is "alignment", right?

Comment: @anatolyg The question is that I need help writing the hex code for the thunk that will do the trick. I'm aiming to do the first variant of Jester answer but I don't know how to get the hex code of given assembly

Comment: Run it through an assembler of course. Then again, it's also trivial to look up the opcode for `push` and `pop` by hand.

Comment: @Jester, why in your first answer the stack isn't aligned ?

Comment: To be precise, it's only 4 byte aligned. If your environment requires more than that, it won't work. Linux for example wants 16 bytes, but given you use `stdcall` I assume windows.

Comment: @Jester Yes I'm working on windows, would the first solution work or it'll be killed by kernel ?

Comment: I believe it should work. Note that you will have to place the code into executable memory though.